# Hands detection with Mediapipe, only works stable if the fce its also in the video frame (Python)

Tags: python, mediapipe

Doing hands detection only works accurate if the face its also in the video stream, if the camera only can see the hands doesn't work efficiency, this its supposed to be like that or there is a way to prevent this behavior.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you using MediaPipe holistic or MediaPipe Hands?

Comment: I am using holistic

Comment: I am using a LSTM model to track movement